display the labels from fill on x axis
df <- data.frame(x1=c("A","B1","B2","C1","C2","C3"), x2=c("A","B","B","C","C","C"), y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

I'm looking for a way to dodge the bars based on x2 but display the x1 labels on the x axis. I can do something like this:
p <- ggplot(aes(x=x2, y=y, fill=x1), data=df)
p + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")

which dodges the bars correctly, but now I don't know how to replace the x2 labels with the x1 labels on the x axis.

One option would be to map x1 on x but facet by x2 to group your bars. For the facets I use facet_grid as it allows for bras of equal width using space="free_x". But if that is not desired you can of course switch to facet_wrap():
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x = x1, y = y, fill = x1), data = df) +
  geom_col(width = 1) +
  facet_grid(~x2,
    scales = "free_x",
    switch = "x",
    space = "free_x"
  ) +
  theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.text = element_blank(),
  )



Nice. You can also insert theme_minimal() + before the theme() to get a plot that "hides" the facetting.
